Continuous Time Markov Chains -Markov Property (2.4.1)
I do not understand the first part of the proof of this theorem from the book Markov Chains by J.R. Norris.
Why does he mention that " It suffices to prove the claim conditional on the event $X_s = i$"? Does the claim hold even if I do not condition on $X_s$?
Theorem 2.4.1 (Markov property). Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$. Then, for any $s \geq 0$, $(X_{s+t} - X_s)_{t \geq 0}$ is also a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$, independent of $(X_r : r \leq s)$.
Proof. It suffices to prove the claim conditional on the event $X_s = i$, for each $i \geq 0$. Set $\tilde{X}_t = X_{s+t} - X_s$. We have
$$
\{X_s = i\} = \{J_i \leq s < J_{i+1}\} = \{J_i \leq s\} \cap \{S_{i+1} > s - J_i\}.
$$
On this event
$$
X_r = \sum_{j=1}^i \mathbf{1}_{\{S_j \leq r\}} \quad \text{for } r \leq s
$$
and the holding times $\tilde{S}_1, \tilde{S}_2, \dots$ of $(\tilde{X}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ are given by
$$
\tilde{S}_1 = S_{i+1} - (s - J_i), \quad \tilde{S}_n = S_{i+n} \quad \text{for } n \geq 2
$$
as shown in the diagram.
